# Add active class without removing when clicked twice

Tags: jquery, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuKqw/60/

What would allow the 'active' class to remain attached to an item when it is clicked twice? The intended behavior is that only whe a NEW tab is clicked does it change classes. Otherwise, if the same tab is clicked twice for example, it should remain 'active' not toggle between active and inactive.

```
$('nav li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Reference: [Jquery change class on click menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389334/jquery-change-class-on-click-menu)

---

I ended up breaking it out into a function:
http://jsfiddle.net/vuKqw/72/

```
function tabchange() { 
 var parent = $(this).parent();
    if(!parent.hasClass('active')) {
        parent.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}
};

$('nav li a').click(tabchange)​
```

Thank you @Madbreaks for the answer- that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first to see if the parent is active:

```
$('nav li a').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if(!parent.hasClass('active')){
        parent.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Note the use of 'addClass' instead of 'toggleClass' - better to be more specific in situations where you know exactly what you're doing (the intent there is only ever to add the class).

Cheers

Comment: Perfect, other than that you're missing a closing ) in your if evaluation. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed I was, fixed.  Glad I could help.